# Compare types in Scala

Tags: scala

I have two objects, each with locally defined types, and I want to determine if the types are the same. For example, I'd like this code to compile:

```
trait Bar {
  type MyType
}

object Bar {
  def compareTypes(left: Bar, right: Bar): Boolean = (left.MyType == right.MyType)
}
```

However, compilation fails with "value MyType is not a member of Bar".

What's going on? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this, but it takes a little extra machinery:

```
trait Bar {
  type MyType
}

object Bar {
  def compareTypes[L <: Bar, R <: Bar](left: L, right: R)(
    implicit ev: L#MyType =:= R#MyType = null
  ) = ev != null
}
```

Now if we have the following:

```
val intBar1 = new Bar { type MyType = Int }
val intBar2 = new Bar { type MyType = Int }
val strBar1 = new Bar { type MyType = String }
```

It works as expected:

```
scala> Bar.compareTypes(intBar1, strBar1)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> Bar.compareTypes(intBar1, intBar2)
res1: Boolean = true
```

The trick is to ask for implicit evidence that `L#MyType` and `R#MyType` are the same, and to provide a default value (`null`) if they aren't. Then you can just check whether you get the default value or not.

Comment: If one leaves out the default value of null, this would be a full compile time check, which I would prefer in this case because all types are known at compile time.

Comment: @sschaef, I don't think all types are known at compile time. For example, in the following bar.MyType isn't determined until runtime: "val bar: Bar = if (/* flip coin */) intBar1 else strBar1"

Comment: At runtime you do not have abstract types any more. Thus, the implicit parameter list is filled in at compiletime and comparisons to your example will always return false.