# Scala - Perform Operation on two objects only if an inner field is equal

Tags: scala, generics, type-erasure

If I have

```
Class Box[+T] {
   num: Int,
   t: T
}
```

And I want to make a method which adds two boxes together, but really it just adds num and creates a new Box, how would I do that but ensuring both t's are equal? I don't want just the type to be the same, but the inner part of t to be the same

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
def add[T](box1: Box[T], box2: Box[T]): Option[Box[T]] = {
  if(box1.t == box2.t) Some(Box(box1.num + box2.num, box1.t))
  else None
}
```

Comment: does this work in the context of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700693/compare-types-in-scala

Comment: @JoelBerkeley I think it should. Also, this is OK I suppose. I was hoping to avoid the Option. It seems there would not be a way to get safety at compilation (without having Option return type) even if we restricted it to the same object reference must be in each Box. The thing is it's more of a programmer error that someone would try to add two different boxes, which is why I don't like the Option; it seems more silent. I'm wondering if it would be better to throw an exception or have a require( ) statement used instead